# 403 Forbidden for index.php on Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to configure a simple wordpress site in nginx on Ubuntu. I'm no linux expert, but I usually manage between following tutorials online and tweaking a few bits myself. I've also had this very site running on a previous server with nginx, which I configured myself. I've migrated to a new server but I'm setting things up slightly differently this time round, so starting from scratch.

I've got nginx, php, and mysql installed and configured. I know php is working as I have checked it with domain.com/php.info. However, when I try to access domain.com or domain.com/index.php I get 403 forbidden. If I point the server block to index.html, that is served correctly.

I have set folder permissions to 755 and files to 644, and the owner to www-data.

If I rename index.php to index2.php, I can access the page at domain.com/index2.php but if I then point the server block to index2.php, I still get error 403.

I thought my server block config must be wrong, so I used the generator at digitalocean but the result is the same. I've tried almost every suggestion I can find on google and nothing has worked. Config below, can anyone help? Thanks!

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl http2;
    listen              [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name         www.example.com;
    set                 $base /var/www/example.com;
    root                $base/;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    # security
    include             nginxconfig.io/security.conf;

    # logging
    access_log          /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log           /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log warn;

    # index.php
    index               index.php;

    # index.php fallback
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    #also tried the alternatives below
        #try_files $uri /index.php;
        #try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    # additional config
    include nginxconfig.io/general.conf;
    include nginxconfig.io/example.com.wordpress.conf;

    # handle .php
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        include      nginxconfig.io/php_fastcgi.conf;
    }
}

# non-www, subdomains redirect
server {
    listen              443 ssl http2;
    listen              [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name         .example.com;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    return              301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name .example.com;
    return      301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Is there an `.htaccess` file near your index.php ?

Comment: I have no .htaccess files